# commited many directories to a git package, deleted them, but python setup.py still thinks they are there

Tags: python-3.x, git

I made a small python software package using git. This is just a local package, not a pypi package. I install it onto my system by simply going `python setup.py install` and this works like a charm.

However, part of what the package does is generate a database, and I accidently generated the database inside the package and committed the hundreds of folders to the git project

i.e., I made the hundreds of folders and then

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
```

I then installed it
`python setup.py install`

I have now gone back and deleted all of the folders and redone `git add .` `git commit -m "fix?"`

however when I do `python setup.py install` it still churns through the hundreds of folders during the install. The install is usually almost instantaneous, it is a small package, but it takes about 30 seconds now :S

How do I clean this up? the hundreds of folders have already been deleted.

Comment: A *repository* consists of a collection of *commits*. Each commit consists of a snapshot of *every file*, as a sort of permanent archive of the state as of that commit, plus metadata about the commit. Removing a bunch of files adds a new snapshot that lacks those files, but the existing commits, which still exist, still contain all those files.

Comment: Hmmm, I am not all that git savvy. I imagine then that I need to go back and permanently remove the bad commit from the record?

Comment: If you don't like the set of commits that you have in your repository, you can add new commits to the repository. You can't actually *remove* any existing commits, but if you stop using them entirely, and make it impossible to *find* them, Git will eventually delete them as unwanted junk. Alternatively, if you prefer—this is relatively easy albeit boring and repetitive and dull and full of repeat work—you can create a new, totally empty repository, check out one old commit in the *old* repo, copy the desired files over to the *new* repo, commit, etc.

Comment: Since this is a job from the Department of Redundancy Department, which computers are good at, people have automated it. Search for "remove large files" and the like.

Comment: the files are removed, that part was easy. I am just stuck getting the setup.py install to be a small amount of time now :S I will probably take your advice and make a fresh repo

Comment: I'm talking about repeatedly, one commit at a time, taking old commits that are Bad in some way (have unwanted files) and copying them to New And Improved Good Commits, committing those, and then making sure that you no longer user any of the old commits, by using the new and improved ones instead. The automated tools do this. Some of them even clean out the Old-And-Lousy commits entirely (and some don't).

Comment: The tools I know of are: "The BFG" (spelled just like that), `git filter-branch` (a very klunky and hard to use tool that comes with Git), and `git filter-repo` (a replacement for filter-branch, that doesn't come with Git yet because it's still being worked-on). I'm sure there are probably dozens of others.

Comment: @torek okay, sounds good. Looks like I have my morning cut out for me ;) thanks!

Comment: @torek I just realized I am still confused because I would not expect `python setup install` to build a commit that is old i.e., why is python doing an install thinking the package contains folders that were deleted many commits ago?

Comment: It probably isn't: it's just that `git clone`, of that repository, still has to copy every *commit* from that repository. This takes ages because some of those commits are very large.